# Apphooks in django cms 3

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using django cms 3 for my new project and i have used apphook for a django cms page. As the project having Arabic and English version, the corresponding page gets published only in a single language, not in both. How to make the page get published in both versions. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go into cms pages admin list, you will see some colored dots...:

[image]

and check settings.py:

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', gettext('French')),
    ('de', gettext('German')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
```

Comment: I tried to publish the page in Arabic, but asusual it redirects to the structure of the page but there is no "Publish changes" button showing for Arabic page.